# Select rows of numpy.ndarray where the first row number is inside some list

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'm looking for a short readable way to select some rows of an 2D numpy.ndarray, where the first number of each row is in some list.

Example:

```py
>>> index
[4, 8]

>>> data 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
      [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
      [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
      [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

So in this case i only need

```py
 array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

because the first numbers of these rows are 4 and 8 which are listed in `index`.

Basically im looking for something like:

```py
data[data[:,0] == i if i in index]
```

which of course is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to check, then index as usual:

```
idx = [4, 8]

data = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
                 [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
                 [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
                 [12, 13, 14, 15]])

>>> data[np.isin(data[:,0], idx)]
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list comprehension, here's how (`isin` is undoubtably better for this usage case, though):

```
>>> np.array([e for e in data if e[0] in index])
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```