# Selecting specific rows of numpy.ndarray containing numpy.ndarrays of different size

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a `numpy.ndarray` containing `numpy.ndarray's` of different size and i want to extract some rows where the first number of each of these rows are in a certain list.

Example:

```py
>>>a
array([array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 1, 1]), array([2, 3, 3, 4])], dtype=object)

>>> idx
[2]
```

I need:

```py
>>>a
array([array([2, 3]), array([2, 3, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

So i want only the rows (or arrays) of a which have a 2 as the first number. Is there a simple and nice way to do so like in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121738/select-rows-of-numpy-ndarray-where-the-first-row-number-is-inside-some-list/53121953#53121953)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object dtype array like this is more like a list of lists than a 2d array.  `a` actually has pointers to the element arrays, just a list would.

```
In [517]: a=array([array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 1, 1]), array([2, 3, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
In [518]: a
Out[518]: 
array([array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 1, 1]), array([2, 3, 3, 4])],
      dtype=object)
```

A straightforward way of selecting the elements of `a` that match this criteria is to use a list comprehension:

```
In [519]: [row for row in a if row[0]==2]
Out[519]: [array([2, 3]), array([2, 3, 3, 4])]
```

Almost all operations on an object dtype array like this involve a list iteration like this.